# Universal Dropdown Menu?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-select

I am trying to create a "quick links" dropdown for a site I'm designing and it has to be compatible for all browsers IE6 and up. It needs to remain 120px wide because its position will be static. Using the `<select>` tag and setting a width, this works; however, when the box is opened, IE cuts off the longer texted links where Firefox resizes them correctly. Is there anyway to define the dropdowns at a different width than the 120px top of the box that works with all browsers?

If not, is there a simple script for a customizable dropdown menu that doesn't require 10 pages of javascript?

Answer (score 2):

check out http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/

Answer (score 1):

If the A List Apart [suckerfish](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/) is of interest, you should take a look at the updated [son of suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) for inspiration. 12 lines of javascript code + multiple line support.

For reference, here is a [thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3580296.htm) that discusses the problems & offers solutions to support the nuances of ie6 & ie7 with son of suckerfish (but applicable to all menuing implementations).